# Writing Objects members to Parcels

Tags: java, android, serialization, parcelable, parcel

So far I've been chugging along with `Parcelable` objects without issue, mainly because all of their members have been types that have `writeX()` methods associated with them. For example, I do:

```
public String name;

private Foo(final Parcel in) {
    name = in.readString(); }
public void writeToParcel(final Parcel dest, final int flags) {
    dest.writeString(name); }
```

But now if I have a `Bar` member things get a little dicey for me:

```
public Bar bar;

private Foo(final Parcel in) {
    bar = new Bar(); //or i could actually write some constructor for Bar, this is a demo.
    bar.memberString = in.readString();
}

public void writeToParcel(final Parcel dest, final int flags) {
    // What do I do here?
}
```

Am I approaching this the wrong way? What should I do in my `writeToParcel` to parcel member `Bar`s?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The correct and more OO way is make Bar implements Parcelable too.

To read Bar in your private Foo constructor:

```
private Foo(final Parcel in) {
  ... ...
  bar = in.readParcelable(getClass().getClassLoader());
  ... ...
}
```

To write Bar in your writeToParcel method:

```
public void writeToParcel(final Parcel dest, final int flags) {
  ... ...
  dest.writeParcelable(bar, flags);
  ... ...
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: adding because some might get confuse here **getClass().getClassLoader()** means **Bar.class.getClassLoader()**

Comment: What should I do if my class is provided by the SDK and cannot be modified?

Answer (score 0):

Parceables are a pain and only pass by value and not reference. I would never recommend using them. Make a static model instance if you application and just get a shim reference to the object you need.

Comment: Using singletons as a design principle is flawed in object oriented programming. Deserialize into json or store the values, do not have a global class all your other classes can access.